# DirectX Crash When Resizing Tiny

Tags: c++, resize, directx, buffer

I am trying to make my program more bullet proof. My program resizes fine until I make it super tiny like this:

[image]

A method to prevent that from happening is to set a minimum size, which I know how to do already. I want to look deeper into the problem before I do that.

The following is where the functions start to crash.

```
hr=swapChain->ResizeBuffers(settings.bufferCount, settings.width, settings.height, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0);
if(FAILED(hr)) return 0;
```

I figured it was because the buffer was too small, so I made a fail safe buffer size. It also failed though.

```
hr=swapChain->ResizeBuffers(settings.bufferCount, fallback.width, fallback.height, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0);
if(FAILED(hr)) return 0;
```

**What is the reason the program chokes when I make it tiny?** I thought it was the buffers being too small. Doesnt seem like it is the case.

**Edit:**
Been a while since I posted this, so my code has changed a lot. Now it gives an unhandled exception crash when calling **deviceContext->ClearRenderTargetView()**.

Comment: Are `fallback.width` and `fallback.height` positive?

Comment: Yep. I even manually set them to 640, 480

Comment: It doesnt throw an error. It seems to just freeze.

Comment: Since my code change, it crashes instead of freezes. I get an unhandled exception crash when I make the window tiny.