# DirectX Crash On Minimize

Tags: c++, windows, resize, directx, directx-11

I have a simple DirectX program that crashes when I minimize & then unminimize.

These are the event cases I cover:

```
case WM_SIZING:
case WM_SIZE:
    if(engine.isReady()) engine.resizeDevice();
    if(engine.isReady()) engine.draw();
    break;
```

The resize is roughly:

```
deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(0, NULL, NULL);
    ...
deviceInterface->CreateRenderTargetView( ... );
    ...
deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &vp);
    ...
deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &renderTargetInterface, NULL);
```

When I unminimize, the code dies while trying to set the back buffer. This is the line with the values passed:
**hr=swapChain->ResizeBuffers(3, 640, 480, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0);**
ResizeBuffers() returns error 0x887a0005

Back buffer code:

```
HRESULT _setBackBuffer(const SettingsVD &settings){
    HRESULT hr;

    hr=swapChain->ResizeBuffers(settings.bufferCount, settings.width, settings.height, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr; // Dies here when UNminimizing

    ID3D11Texture2D* backBuffer=NULL;
    hr=swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(backBuffer), (LPVOID*)&backBuffer);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    hr=deviceInterface->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer, NULL, &renderTargetInterface);
    if(FAILED(hr)) return hr;

    release(backBuffer);

    return hr;
}
```

Anyone know why the back buffer is barfing?

- Might be related to my other thread, [DirectX Crash When Resizing Tiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12949520/directx-crash-when-resizing-tiny), but I havent solve that problem yet, so....bump.

Answer (score 1):

Just a remainder, you should better handle the minimize message(SIZE_MINIMIZED) separately in WM_SIZE, if the windows was minimized, stop rendering and yield the CPU time to other programs.